# Symmetry preserving graph products

Tags: graph-theory

#### Motivation

For vertex-transitive graphs $G_1, G_2$ the [Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product_of_graphs) $G_1\square G_2$ is vertex-transitive, too. I am looking for generalized graph products that have the same property, but allow to construct more vertex-transitive graphs than it is possible with the Cartesian product alone.

#### Definitions

> Cartesian product $G \square H$:
>
> 1. $V(G \square H) = V(G) \times V(H)$
> 2. $(gh)(g'h') \in E(G \square H)$ iff
>
>    - $g = g'$ and $hh' \in E(H)$ or
>    - $h = h'$ and $gg' \in E(G)$

Let $G_1, G_2$ be (finite) graphs with vertex sets $V_1, V_2$.

Let $N_1, N_2$ be the [normalizers of the resp. automorphism groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/172193/normalizers-of-automorphism-groups), i.e. symmetry preserving permutations.

Let $\pi_1, \pi_2$ be mappings $\pi_1: V_1 \rightarrow N_2$, $\pi_2: V_2 \rightarrow N_1$, i.e. each vertex of one of the graphs is mapped to a symmetry preserving permutation of the other graph. Let $\pi := (\pi_1,\pi_2)$.

> Symmetry perserving product $G \square_\pi H$:
>
> 1. $V(G \square_\pi H) = V(G) \times V(H)$
> 2. $(gh)(g'h') \in E(G \square_\pi H)$ iff
>
>    - $g = g'$ and $\pi_1^{-1}(g)(hh') \in E(H)$ or
>    - $h = h'$ and $\pi_2^{-1}(h)(gg') \in E(G)$

#### Example

For $G = C_5$, $H = K_2$ and

- $\pi_1(i) = \text{id}$ for $i=1,\dots,5$
- $\pi_2(1) = \text{id}$
- $\pi_2(2) = (1)(2354)$

we find, that the Petersen graph is $C_5 \square_\pi K_2$:

[image] [<sup>(source)</sup>](http://epublius.de/mathoverflow/vt2.png)

#### Questions

Does the **conjecture**

> $G\square_\pi H$ is vertex-transitive for all vertex-transitive graphs $G,H$
> and symmetry preserving mappings $\pi$.

hold?

Assuming that the answer is positive, consider the set $\Gamma$ of constructable vertex-transitive graphs which could be defined inductively:

- $K_n \in \Gamma$
- $C_n \in \Gamma$
- if $G \in \Gamma$ then the complement $\ \overline{G} \in \Gamma$
- if $G,H \in \Gamma$ and $\pi$ is a symmetry preserving mapping, then $\ G\square_\pi H \in \Gamma$

I wonder how the set of constructable vertex-transitive graphs might be characterized, resp. what are necessary and/or sufficient conditions. Or the other way around: which vertex-transitive graphs are **not** constructable, and how many are there asymptotically?

**EDIT**: I omitted an intermediate step: Let $\pi_i: V(G_i) \rightarrow \text{Aut}(G_j)$ be an adjacency preserving mapping. I am quite sure that the conjecture

> $G\square_\pi H$ is vertex-transitive for all vertex-transitive graphs $G,H$
> and *adjacency* preserving mappings $\pi$.

holds.

Comment: Such a product (unless it's trivial) must have a degree at most half of the number of vertexes.  There are transitive graphs of almost any number of vertexes and degree (odd number of vertexes and odd degree is forbidden): in fact, there's a circulant with any degree (a circulant is a graph with an automorphism that is a cyclic permutation moving all vertices).

Comment: Also, the complement of any transitive graph is transitive.  The case when one of the factors is $ K_2 $ might thus require special examination, because that's the only way a product can have a degree near half the number of vertexes.  

Comment: Aaron's example $K_6$ minus a matching has degree 4 which is more than half the number of vertices. Did I misunderstand your argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Revised answer** (see previous version to make sense of comments):

The Petersen graph is a small wonderful and rather exceptional creature. It is not a paradigm.

Does this graph fit your construction with $G = C_7$, $H = K_2$ ?

[image]

It is not vertex transitive since each red node is in three $5$-cycles but each green node is only in two.

There are many vertex transitive graphs with a prime number of vertices, none of them is a product. So there are graphs which do not arise in this manner.

Your construction takes two graphs $G_i$ with $v_i$ vertices each of degree $d_i$ and some permutations and creates a new one with $v_1v_2$ vertices each of degree $d_1+d_2.$ This can work out to be a rather low degree (or high if a complement is taken.) Consider the Johnson graph $J(6,2)$ whose $\binom{6}{2}=15$ nodes are the pairs from an $6$ set with two adjacent when they share an element. It has degree $2(6-2)=8.$ If it is to be a product then we need $v_1=3$ and $v_2=5$ which allows for degree at most $2+4=6.$ This also does not allow the product to be the complement a regular graph of degree $7.$ A similar obstacle would arise for  many vertex transitive graphs just based on the number of vertices and the degree. Certainly for $J(n,2)$ when $n \ge 6$ makes $\binom{n}2$ odd and probably even when $\binom{n}2$ it is even.

Comment: Are you sure that your permutation $\pi_2(2)$ is in the normalizer of $\text{Aut}(C_m)$?

Comment: $K_6$ minus a matching equals the complement of three copies of $K_2$ and thus is constructable according to my definition. 

Comment: You are right on both points, I wasn't paying enough attention. My feeling however is simple examples will show problems in all directions. I don't think $C_3 \square_\pi C_m$ would usually be vertex transitive. I might be wrong again. Even $K_2 \square_\pi C_{11}$ seems problematic sometimes.

Comment: Could you please give me a hint, how $K_2\square_\pi C_{11}$ could be problematic.

Comment: I am thinking about $C_3\square_\pi C_4 = K_3\square_\pi C_4$ and how it could pose a problem. If this is not the smallest counter-example, maybe $C_3\square_\pi C_5 = K_3\square_\pi C_5$? (Looking for counter-examples is appropriate if one doubts a conjecture. I still believe in it - until I see a counter-example. So I should try to prove the conjecture - that $G\square_\pi H$ is vertex-transitive for vertex-transitive $G,H$.) Nevertheless I'd appreciate any worked-out counter-example!

Comment: Thank you very much for this elaborate answer! Now I am convinced.

Comment: @Aaron: By the way: how do *you* draw such graphs?

Comment: I used Google Sketchup which is a pretty silly way to do it but free and easy to use.

Answer (score 2):

There was a paper I saw some years ago that discussed many possible ways of defining the product of two graphs. I am not sure but I think it was this paper:

> Nowakowski, Richard J.(3-DLHS); Rall,
>   Douglas F.(1-FURM) [Associative graph
>   products and their independence,
>   domination and coloring numbers.](http://www.discuss.wmie.uz.zgora.pl/php/discuss3.php?ip=&url=pdf&nIdA=3544&nIdSesji=-1)
>   (English summary)  Discuss. Math.
>   Graph Theory 16 (1996), no. 1, 53–79.

It might be worth checking out, if you want to look at different products.